# Does netstat show open ephemeral ports?

Tags: windows, port

I chatted with one PhD student in my group and he told me that Windows has 2,500 open UDP ports.

Thus, if some ephemeral port is used within 2500 open UDP ports, it'll be difficult for attack to be able to know which port is used since they are all open.

I had never heard of that before so I did some checking in my own environment and found out this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -ab

Active Connections

 TCP    [fe80::fc9b:3f4b:206e:b05%9]:49689  WIN-Test:epmap         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [fe80::fc9b:3f4b:206e:b05%9]:49690  WIN-Test:49667         ESTABLISHED
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::fc9b:3f4b:206e:b05%9]:49691  WIN-Test:ldap          ESTABLISHED
 [dns.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::fc9b:3f4b:206e:b05%9]:49695  WIN-Test:epmap         ESTABLISHED
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::fc9b:3f4b:206e:b05%9]:49696  WIN-Test:49667         ESTABLISHED
 [lsass.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:389            *:*
 [lsass.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
  IKEEXT
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50271          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50272          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50273          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50274          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50275          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50276          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50277          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50278          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50279          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50280          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50281          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50282          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50283          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50284          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50285          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50286          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50287          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50288          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50289          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50290          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50291          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50292          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50293          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50294          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50295          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50296          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50297          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50298          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50299          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50300          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50301          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50302          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50303          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50304          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50305          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50306          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50307          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50308          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50309          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50310          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:50311          *:*
 [dns.exe]
```

This is just part of what my terminal showed. The total amount is about 2k.

From spec `0.0.0.0` means the port is listening on all interfaces. The first `*`, in `*:*`, means connections can come from any IP address, and the second `*`, in `*:*`, means the connection can originate from any port on the remote machine. Thus, it's a socket waiting to be connected. However, it doesn't have `LISTENING` but I guess it's open in this case.

Right now, I have the following questions:

1. Usually different interfaces have different ports which means if NIC A and NIC B both have port C open, then, A's C and B's are different things. But from the output, we can see that windows also provide port for that is shared for all NICs. Are these ports available for all NICs permanently? or if some socket is used for some service, this port is used specifically for that NIC.
2. For the 2,500 open udp ports, if the server sends out a UDP packet, will the system only use one of them as the ephemeral port?

I'll do some checks on my own later but I also would like to hear some points related to it.

These ports showed in the terminal seem not open

```
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53161          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53162          *:*
 [dns.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53163          *:*
 [dns.exe]
```

I sent a udp packet to 53162 and Windows sent back a UDP packet and ICMP port unreachable

Based on [Daniel's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1747292/does-netstat-show-open-ephemeral-port#comment2710220_1747292), it seems that the port is opened because of `dns.exe`. So I sent a DNS query to Windows but I also got ICMP port unreachable. However, the A record is sent just before the ICMP.

Comment: No, Windows does not have 2500 “open UDP ports”.

Comment: @DanielB can you explain what are the continuous udp port numbers displayed in my terminal?

Comment: Sure. You have a program, `dns.exe`, that is making lots of outgoing UDP “connections”. Hence the increasing ports in the ephemeral port range. I don’t have any `dns.exe`.

Comment: @DanielB If I understand correctly, these ports are open and are explicitly used for dns.exe. As I posted above, normal DNS, udp will not be accepted by this port and an ICMP port unreachable will occur. Maybe each port is used for a specific socket and there is service behind it. To be accepted through the port, it has to match dns.exe's requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yesterday, I chatted with one PhD student in my group and he told me that windows has 2500 open udp ports. Thus, if some ephemeral port is used within 2500 open udp ports

It's unclear what the student meant by "open", or what sources they have for that claim.

Most commonly, "port is open" means that a program has a socket bound to it, and is waiting to receive packets on that port (which would be shown in netstat) – therefore it is *not available* as an ephemeral port, even if it would normally be within the range.

But as you can see from your netstat output, there are far fewer than 2500 sockets having "open" ports (and only 6 of them are truly listening for requests, the others are temporary sockets that sent out a request and are waiting for a DNS single response each), so it's unlikely that this is what your student meant.

The student *might* have been talking about ephemeral ports, then (which won't show in netstat) – however, 2500 isn't the correct number of ephemeral ports either; the port range happens to be documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang):

| OS version | Port range | Number of ports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows Vista and later | 49152 – 65535 | 16384 |
| Up to Windows XP | 1025 – 5000 | 3976 |

> Thus, it's a socket waiting to be connected. However, it doesn't have LISTENING but I guess it's open in this case.

There are no protocol states to be shown because UDP doesn't have any (unlike TCP which has an actual state machine).

Although a UDP socket can be bound to a remote address:port, this is a local operation and doesn't change anything about how the protocol behaves; it's always in the same state.

But if those were TCP sockets with a state, roughly 5-6 of them would be "LISTENING" while the rest (all the dns.exe sockets) would most likely be "ESTABLISHED" as they resulted from an outbound query.

> Usually different interfaces have different ports which means if NIC A and NIC B both have port C open, then, A's C and B's are different things.

TCP/UDP ports are *not* associated with interfaces, but with local IP addresses. Depending on network routing, a packet to B's address may actually arrive through interface A, but it will still match a socket bound to B's address. On the other hand, an interface may have multiple IP addresses – if a socket is bound to address B1, it will not accept packets sent to address B2, even if it's to the "same" port.

So if netstat shows that a socket is bound to `10.0.0.5:22`, then it literally means it's associated with the local address 10.0.0.5, regardless of what interface it's configured on.

> But from the output, we can see that windows also provide port for that is shared for all NICs. Are these ports available for all NICs permanently? or if some socket is used for some service, this port is used specifically for that NIC.

0.0.0.0 matches *all* IPv4 local addresses at any time, including addresses that may be added in the future.

> For the 2500 open udp ports, if the server sends out a UDP packet, will the system only use one of them as the ephemeral port?

netstat does not show you the pool of "available" ephemeral ports – quite the opposite, it only shows ports associated with specific sockets. For example, local port 50311 is listed because it is currently in use by that particular socket (and therefore removed from the ephemeral port pool).

Thus packets sent by dns.exe through that socket will use 50311 as the local port, but ports sent through any other socket will need to use a different local port.